# Finding the 24V C-wire from Carrier AC blower to connect to a Smart Thermostat

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire

I want to install a Smart Thermostat to control my AC unit. The current "dumb" thermostat is battery powered and does not use a C-wire (see current thermostat wiring pic). When I look at the wiring diagram for the control board it seems relatively clear that a brown wire coming from the receptacle is the one that should be the C-wire (see pics). It appears that it is pigtailed to a white wire, however, and I am not sure if I should just attach the blue wire (which I plan to use as the C-wire to the thermostat) to this wirenut or separately connect wire the brown and the blue wires and separately cap off the white wire that it is connected to.

[image: Old Thermostat Connections]
[image: AC Blower wiring diagram]
[image: Current connections to thermostat - location of what I think is the brown wire indicated to be C-wire in wiring diagram]
[image: Wires emerging from the "recp" indicated on the wiring diagram]

Comment: You are correct ! In your case the Brown is the C wire

Answer (score 1):

### Just connect the blue wire in with the existing brown/white wires

You should incorporate the blue wire into the existing junction of the brown and white wires.  That way, the blue wire will provide C to the thermostat without interfering with the C wire return from the condensing unit's compressor contactor, something that's very important to have otherwise your air conditioner won't work.

Comment: Thanks!  Just the information I was looking for.